# Getting access to structure non-array element

Tags: c, indexing, structure

I've declared a structure in my code `struct Stdinfo` which contains name and score of students.

```
#include <stdio.h>
        struct Stdinfo{
        char name[30];
        int score;
    };
```

Then I created this structure inside a function with the name of `struct Stdinfo CreatStruct()`. It also should be mention that my structure variable is array. After the structure is made I stored its address in a pointer `struct Stdinfo *structPtr`. Then I passed the address to the function below:

```
void FindAverage(struct Stdinfo *structPtr ,size_t stdnum){

        int j;

        for(j = 1 ; j < stdnum ; j++ ) 
            {
                //Error line
                if( (structPtr[j] -> score) <  (structPtr[j] -> score ) ) { 

                    /*...
                     * 
                     * ?
                     * 
                     */ 


                    }
            }

            ////printf(The answer);
    }
```

my whole code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Stdinfo{
        char name[30];
        int score;
    };

struct Stdinfo CreatStruct();
void FindAverage(struct Stdinfo * ,size_t );

int main(void)
{
    //Number of students ~stdnum
    size_t stdnum;
    int i; 
    puts("Input numbers of student(s) :") ;
    scanf("%Iu" ,&stdnum);

    struct Stdinfo student[stdnum]  ; 

    //Filling array of structure
    for(i=0 ; i < stdnum ; i++)
    {
        student[i] = CreatStruct() ;
    }

    struct Stdinfo *structPtr;
    structPtr= student;
    FindAverage(structPtr ,stdnum);

    return 0;
}

struct Stdinfo CreatStruct() {

    struct Stdinfo student;

    getchar(); // Consume newline from previous input

    printf("Input the name of the student : ") ;
    fgets(student.name , sizeof (student.name) , stdin);
    // remove trailing newline from 'fgets()'
    student.name[strcspn(student.name, "\n")] = 0;

    puts("Input his(her) score:") ; 
    scanf("%i" ,&student.score) ;

    return student ; 
}

void FindAverage(struct Stdinfo *structPtr ,size_t stdnum){

    int j;

    for(j = 1 ; j < stdnum ; j++ ) 
        {
            if( ( structPtr[j] -> score ) <  ( structPtr[j] -> score ) ) { //Error line

                /*...
                 * 
                 * ?
                 * 
                 */ 


                }
        }

        ////printf(The answer);
}
```

My **goal** is to print the greatest score but I don't know how to get access to it.

I appreciate if anyone helps me to solve this problem.

Comment: Which error do you get in `Error line`?

Comment: I do not understand why `if(structPtr[j]->score < structPtr[j]->score)`, having removed unnecesary spaces and parentheses.

Comment: @MondKin-  if( ( structPtr[j] -> score ) <  ( structPtr[j] -> score ) )

Comment: @Pouyan and which error do you get in that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `structPtr[j] ->` with `structPtr[j].`

The error you're having is because you're dereferencing the array twice. The `->` operator is just syntactic sugar for `(*x).`, and `[N]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(x + N)`so in your case, `structPtr[j]->` translates to `**(structPtr + j)`, when in order to access the array you need to dereference it only once like this: `*(structPtr + j)`.